# Servlet unavailable http 404

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

Am simply experimenting with jsp and wanted to display all entries in a table,

my servlet is this

```
        package UserPass;

        import data.UserPassDb;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
        import javax.servlet.ServletException;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

        /**
        *
        * @author One
        */
        public class UserPassController extends HttpServlet {


            @Override
            protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {

                doPost(request,response);
            }


            @Override
            protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {

                request.setAttribute("users", UserPassDb.selectAllUser());

                String forward = "/me/testpage.jsp";
                RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
                view.forward(request, response);

            }



        }
```

and my test page

```
     <a href="<c:url value='/test/TestServlet'/>">
      refresh
      </a><br><br>


    <c:forEach var="user" items="${users}">

        <c:out value="${user.user_name}"/> 

    </c:forEach>
```

THANKS GUYS.. Am doing tutorials and trying to resolve those beginner problems on my own but failing repeatedly :(

Comment: so what am trying to do here is , to load the servlet in order to get the session object which holds the users data

Comment: Is "/test/TestServlet" the absolute path to the applet or is it meant to be a relative path?  If so remove the leading slash.

Comment: can you publish your web.xml config file here

Comment: it's meant to be absolute actually, though I tried both anyhow and still same.. also my other servlets are kind of working with similar path structure

Comment: Put your mouse above the `[servlets]` tag below the question until a black box shows up and click therin the *info* link. By the way, the phrase "the session object" makes no utter sense here.

Comment: <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.TestServlet</servlet-class>           <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/TestServlet</url-pattern>

Comment: yes you are right, there's no session object involved here, meant request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why so far but it's this

```
     <a href="<c:url value='/TestServlet'/>" >
```

Comment: THANKS EVERYBODY FOR YOUR SUPPORT

Comment: not so happy though, the servlet doesn't display anything ! the users don't display now :(

Comment: I think this is actually wrong, something is not right...with this I don't get an erorr but it doesn't really call the Servlet I think, It doesn't redirect to the desired page which is basically refreshing the same page. it just stays blank with me/TestServlet

Answer (score 0):

Add the annotation `@WebServlet("/TestServlet")` in your class or add your servlet in `web.xml`.

Try to access the servlet from your browser, and check if you can access the servlet.
(probably with the url  : `http://localhost:8080/Test/TestServlet`)

Comment: The thing is I do have another package, Cart and that works just nice,

Comment: if you call here your `Cart` servlet  instead of `TestServlet` it gets called? just trying to locate the problem

Comment: well, at least now i know there's nothing wrong with the code itself,

Comment: i mean it's literally mentioning /me/test/TestServlet does not exist, strange .. am trying to see what's wrong i'll keep it posted

Comment: it's a long shot, but sometimes you need to clean your application server, if using tomcat, check WEB-INF/classes to see if the servlet class exist, I'm out of options frankly :P